# Using google drive API from C#

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I need to work with Google Drive from my UI .NET application. I found that Google uses OAuth 2.0 for authentication. The problem is as far as I understood [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) sends your token back using HTTP callback, but I don't have a web-server running, it's not a web application at all, does it mean I can't use Google Drive SDK from Windows Forms/Windows Console applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The token will be returned to you in a web response to your request for web token. No web server is required.

See these examples and resources

- [Twitter OAuth authentication using .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/247336/Twitter-OAuth-authentication-using-Net)
- [A Simple Guide to using OAuth with C#](http://www.deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/a-simple-guide-to-using-oauth-with-c-/49)
- [oauth-dot-net](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-dot-net/)
- [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/)

Comment: I saw in some examples that it always gives callback URL to the API. Thanks, the resources are very informative. I was searching for exactly google drive examples, probably that was the problem. This OAuth is pretty much complicated.